# cshtml forms input type to be shown as a button

Tags: .net, linq, visual-studio-2012, asp-classic

I used this codes to make a register form, but the other one doesn's display as a button, i tried to make the type to be button but I also need the function of the type reset

```
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    <input type="reset" value="Cancel" />
```

I have this in my form but instead of the two to be displayed as buttons the 2nd which is cancel display as a white bar,.. image attached

[image]

How can I make the 2nd appear as a button like the 1st one did?

Comment: I think it depends on the styles that you apply to the button. Can you post your stylesheet aswell?

Comment: solved it, yes it's in the styles, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managing the CSS can display the 2nd as a button